# xslt day duration to year duration

Tags: date, xslt, duration

I have the the following piece of code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="current-date()- xs:date('2000-01-01')"/>
```

that returns

```
P6535D
```

is there a way to convert this to years?

I tried

```
<xsl:value-of select="years-from-duration(current-date()- xs:date(pi:date))"/>
```

but it gave me:

```
0.
```

Comment: Does `(current-date()- xs:date('2000-01-01')) div xs:dayTimeDuration('P365D')` give you a value you can work with?

Comment: It does, but it's workaround, rather than a proper solution. I am just curious why 'years-from-duration' doesnt work, whereas 'days-from-duration' gives a proper output.
days-from-duration(xs:date(current-date()) - xs:date('2000-01-01'))

Comment: Well, see the spec, https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-years-from-duration, says "If $arg is an xs:dayTimeDuration the function returns 0".

Answer (score 0):

So, echoing Pirates of Penzance, how many years is xs:date('2013-02-28') minus xs:date('2012-02-29')?

It's not possible to get the difference between two dates in months/years because the WG found there was no universal agreement on what the answer should be. Especially with months: what do you get if you subtract one month from 2015-03-31?